# How to force Doctrine to read new mapping information

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am working on a Symfony project that uses the Sonata bundle. I have just added the following to my Page.orm.xml file:

```
    <many-to-many field="equivalents" target-entity="AppBundle\Entity\Equivalent">
        <cascade>
            <cascade-all />
        </cascade>
        <join-table name="page_equivalent">
                <join-columns>
                    <join-column name="page_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
                </join-columns>
                <inverse-join-columns>
                    <join-column name="equivalent_id" referenced-column-name="id" unique="true" />
                </inverse-join-columns>
        </join-table>
    </many-to-many>
```

... and I find that when I run `app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` I get a message telling me that my schema is up to date, even though it clearly is not.

Am I misusing this command? If so, is there another way of generating the necessary new table?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a duplicate of [Symfony doctrine:schema:update not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897915/symfony-doctrineschemaupdate-not-working?rq=1)

I found that running `php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata` solved the problem.